# SQLite obtaining client data from same table based on partnerID

Tags: sqlite, join, select

I've spent hours searching for an answer on this and cannot find a solution.

I have single table with client data. Each client has a unique client id, and also has a partner id if they have a partner. The partner would also have their own row with their unique client id and their partners id.

This is how a basic version of the table called Clients would look:

| ClientID | PartnerID | ClientName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 002 | John Doe |
| 002 | 001 | Jane Doe |

I want to write a query that searches for John Doe, and then obtains data about Jane Doe based on the PartnerID when querying John Doe.

The basics I have currently are just querying John Doe

SELECT
ClientName,
PartnerID
FROM
Clients
WHERE Clients.ClientName = 'John Doe'

This of course displays the data for John Doe:

| ClientID | PartnerID | ClientName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 002 | John Doe |

but how can I use the PartnerID from this query to also show me the records for Jane Doe?

Comment: `WHERE PartnerID = '002'`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a way to do this so that I don't need to manually enter the PartnerID for each query? The database contains hundreds of clients, my aim is that I would have something set up that identifies if ClientID (the client) has a Partner (PartnerID), and pulls their data together using the PartnerID contained in ClientID. Rather than having to type the PartnerID in each time.

Comment: If you want to get the row(s) of the table of Partner = '002' then you have to use `WHERE PartnerID = '002'`. If this is not what you want then edit your question and explain better.

Comment: Sounds like you need a `Clients_Partners` xref table.

Comment: @forpas Thank you for your help, I'm new at this and and trying to learn, it's difficult to explain what I want to do because I don't know enough to know what questions to ask. I appreciate your help though.

MarkBenningfield Yes this is they way I'm leaning, would this involve essentially having two identical tables and then in the query have a statement referring to the 2nd table to get data on the partner if there is a partner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery for that:

```sql
SELECT ClientName, PartnerID
FROM Clients
WHERE ClientID IN (
    SELECT PartnerID
    FROM clients
    WHERE Clients.ClientName = 'John Doe')
```

or you can join the table to itself

```sql
SELECT partner.clientName, partner.partnertID
FROM clients
   JOIN clients AS partner ON clients.PartnerID = partner.ClientID
WHERE clients.ClientName = 'John Doe'
```

Both these methods are very common in sql, I suggest you read the sql tutorial in the postresql documentation which is a great starting point in SQL.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/tutorial.html